# Python Regex sub()

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
agentNamesRegex = re.compile(r'Agent (\w)\w*') 

agentNamesRegex.sub(r'\1****', 'Agent Alice told Agent Carol that Agent Eve knew Agent Bob was a double agent.') 

A**** told C**** that E**** knew B**** was a double agent.'
```

So I'm learning python and needed help on the above regex. Please correct me but `'\1'` is for capturing the first word. Two questions:

1. Why is parenthesis needed
2. Why it doesn't work when I change the above lines to:

   ```
   agentNamesRegex = re.compile(r'Agent (\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)\w*') 

   agentNamesRegex.sub(r'\3****', 'Agent Alice told Agent Carol that Agent Eve knew Agent Bob was a double agent.')
   ```

I guess I did not understand the concept of `(\w)` and `\1` in the first place. Can you please help on this? I didn't had any specific output in mind but was trying different things in spider to know regex better and understand the above expression.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is parenthesis needed

Parentheses are used for capturing a group of characters. The `\1` returns the first captured group. In the regular expression `r'Agent (\w)\w*'`, the parentheses around `(\w)` capture the first word character that follows `'Agent '`, which is the first letter of the agent's name. That captured letter is then substituted back into the output in place of the `\1` for each matched substring.

> Why it doesn't work when I change the above lines to:

```
agentNamesRegex = re.compile(r'Agent (\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)\w*')
```

That regular expression is looking for the word 'Agent', followed by a space, followed by 8 or more word characters. Nothing in your input string matches that pattern. (Your agent names are all too short.)

Comment: If nothing is matching the pattern, why is the output "Agent Alice told Agent Carol that Agent Eve knew Agent Bob was a double agent" and not None. Shouldn't the output be None if pattern does not match.

Comment: @Abhi Because you're calling `sub`. Since there are no matches to the pattern, `sub` makes no substitutions, so your output string is the same as your input string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!!